# Get file size while the file is being uploaded with php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

Is it possible to know file size while uploading? So i can make a progress bar using file size

simultaneously.

```
<?php
session_start();
$f_name=$_SESSION['f_name'];  //but file is still being uploading...
echo filesize($f_name);
?>
```

Comment: Php v5.4+ has [session upload progress](http://php.net/manual/en/session.upload-progress.php) which has post content length data.

Comment: i know that but i want to know if it possible to get it with php filesize() function while uploading

Comment: you know you can get file size from the html too, right?

Answer (score 1):

the question is tagged javascript so i would suggest using the progress element and jquery

http://html5doctor.com/the-progress-element/
http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-javascript-file-upload-progress-bar/

---